# Estimating parameters to Falkenhagen equation for viscosity of solutes

Tags: fluid-dynamics, viscosity

[In this answer to a question about viscosity of water in the presence of solutes](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/88984/7665), the Falkenhagen relation is given:

> $$\frac{\eta_s}{\eta_0}=1+A\sqrt{c}$$ where $\eta_s$ is the solution
>   viscosity, $\eta_0$ the solvent viscosity, $A$ a constant that depends
>   on the electrostatic forces on the ions, and $c$ the concentration of
>   the solute.

Now, in what order of magnitude would I assume A? Can one make general statements which group of solutes will be around which order of magnitude, like "expect A to be around $10^{-8}$ for single atom salts and $10^{-5}$ for long chained organics" (numbers plucked out of thin air) or similiar?

p.s. The relation is quoted from a paywalled paper that I can't access.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the book (not paper) is on [Google books](http://books.google.com/books?id=TD3TeErQD-oC&pg=PA407&lpg=PA407&dq=VISCOSITIES+OF+SOLUTIONS+AND+MIXTURES&source=bl&ots=PoBDAOb1eJ&sig=oUBIXkri_NIS5OqPaTPD4x4_aqE&hl=en&sa=X&ei=k-74UpaMFsH8kQfz6YGgDg&ved=0CEgQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=VISCOSITIES%20OF%20SOLUTIONS%20AND%20MIXTURES&f=false) (hopefully the link works, otherwise go to [books.google.com](http://books.google.com/) and search "VISCOSITIES OF SOLUTIONS AND MIXTURES").

It says for salt (NaCl), the values for the three-parameter equation,
$$
\frac{\eta_S}{\eta_0} = 1+A\sqrt{c}+BC + Cc^2,
$$
are given by
$$
A=0.0062 \quad B=0.0793 \quad C=0.0080
$$
Unfortunately, the one-parameter values are not given in that book (at least from my perusal), but I imagine you might be able to approximate it by comparing estimations with the above three-parameter values.

PS: Sorry about not responding to that comment, seems I totally missed that in my feed. Hopefully this answer makes up for that!

Answer (score -1):

Dissolve an extremely high MW hydrophilic polymer to obtain high viscosities (Polyox, vegetable gums, derivatized cellulose).  Dissolve an interactive copolymer (maleic anhydride-alt-styrene and two equivalents of base, hair gels).  Superabsorbent polymers, super slurpers.  Elegant low molecular-mass organic gelators (LMOGs) form reversible networks that build remarkable viscosities at remarkably low concentrations, 1% or less.  2,3-Bis-n-decyloxyanthracene for alcohol, and

http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/cr0302049?journalCode=chreay 
Chem. Rev. 104(3), pp 1201–1218 (2004), review 
http://pubs.acs.org/doi/abs/10.1021/la404258v 
DOI: 10.1021/la404258v

Comment: This does not appear to answer the question, which is about estimating parameters to the Falkenhagen equation.

Comment: "Which dissolved substances have a huge impact on the viscosity of water?"

Comment: "Now, in what order of magnitude would I assume A?" Your comment merely points out that there is an inconsistency between the *title* and *question* (that has now been rectified).